What is it called and what does it mean when a function "equals" another function and provides a body?
Like in this expression:
fun main() = runBlocking { ... }

Are we executing the runBlocking function and passing the { } body in as a functional argument?
What is this called?
I know it immediately executes main because of the parens.

This question is similar to: Why the main routine in Kotlin is accepted as a single-expression?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This is two separate features: single expression functions and passing trailing lambdas.

thanks @LouisWasserman the trailing lambdas is a neat feature of kotlin

This is not a single language feature.
First, you are allowed to use a single expression as the function's body, to replace that function's return value. This is called a single-expression function. For example, the following declarations of f are equivalent:
fun f(): Int {
    return 0
}

fun f() = 0

Second, when a function takes a function type as its last parameter, you can pass a lambda expression to that parameter after the ) of the call:
fun iTakeAFunction(x: Int, f: () -> Unit) { }

// the following are equivalent
iTakeAFunction(0, { println("Hello World") })
iTakeAFunction(0) { println("Hello World") }

This syntax is called trailing lambda.
When the lambda expression is the only parameter that you are passing, you can even omit the ():
fun iTakeAFunction(f: () -> Unit) { }

// the following are equivalent
iTakeAFunction({ println("Hello World") })
iTakeAFunction() { println("Hello World") }
iTakeAFunction { println("Hello World") }

runBlocking is a function like this, so the code in the question desugars to:
fun main(): Unit {
    return runBlocking({ ... })
}

In other words, main simply calls runBlocking with a lambda expression as its parameter.

Yeah, that's how I had interpreted it but its nice to know what's actually happening.
